# Prohibit Letters and Special Characters from Text Box

Tags: vb.net

I have a program where the user enters a quantity in a field and the price is automatically calculated. I want to only allow numbers in this field and can't figure out a way to do so.

All I Currently have is a small pop up message that occurs when a user enters a number over 1000. But it still lets them go through with it if they just click okay.

```
  Private Sub txt2x6LumberQuantity_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt2x6LumberQuantity.TextChanged
        'Text changed event that occurs when the text within the textbox is changed'
        'If statement to check if the number is between 0 and 1000, if is it'll go to the next block of code and if not goes to the else'
        If IsNumeric(txt2x6LumberQuantity.Text) = True Then
            Select Case CInt(txt2x6LumberQuantity.Text)
                Case 0 To 1000
                    'Calculates line total with a function'
                    dec2x6LumberLineTotal = calculate2x6LumberLineTotal(CDec(lbl2x6LumberPrice.Text), CDec(txt2x6LumberQuantity.Text), lbl2x6LumberLineTotal)
                    'Calculates the subtotal'
                    calculateSubtotal(dec2x6LumberLineTotal, dec2x4LumberLineTotal, decOneHalfPlywoodLineTotal, decFiveEighthsPlywoodLineTotal, decNailsLineTotal, decBradsLineTotal, decGalvanizedScrewLineTotal, decSledgeHammerLineTotal, decFiveDrillBitsLineTotal, decStapleGunLineTotal)
                    'Calculates the tax'
                    calculateTax(decSubtotal)
                Case Else
                    MsgBox("Choose a quantity between 0 and 1000", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Quantity entered is invlaid.")
                    txt2x6LumberQuantity.Focus()
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a NumericUpdown so you can avoid code like that?  Or use Validation events rather than watch keystrokes to scold them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOveflow. Please follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking good questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: This may be one of the most oft-asked questions by beginners. If you can't figure out a way to do it then I can only conclude that you haven't actually searched the web for ideas and if you haven't done that then posting a qu4estion here is premature.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
USING THE VALIDATE EVENT PROCEDURE

```
Private Sub txtAge_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
If Not IsNumeric(txtAge.Text) Then
Cancel = True
ElseIf txtAge.Text < 21 Then
Beep 'give the user some minimal feedback
MsgBox "Enter an age greater than 21"
Cancel = True
'Following is not needed. Placed here for clarity
Else
Cancel = False
End If
End Sub
```